# Are there any features/functions that appbrain.com has that the new market.android.com doesn't?

Tags: google-play-store, app-brain

Are there any features/functions that Appbrain has that the new market.android.com doesn't? If it does, what are they?

Comment: I think you should edit this to make it less subjective.  What are you looking for?  StackExchange isn't a place for general discussion.

Comment: Yes, this seems more as a conversation starter than a question. (Please see the FAQ.) However, Download Squad did a compare-and-contrast of AppBrain and the new Android Market: http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2011/02/03/appbrain-vs-android-market-web-store-which-one-will-rule-supreme/

Comment: I will agree with Matthew and Al on this.  I think it's a great question, but it is very subjective.  A possible rewording that would have definitive answers could be: "Are there any features/functions that Appbrain has that the new market.android.com doesn't? If it does, what are they?"

Comment: @Matt Thanks, I edited and used your wording.   Wasn't trying to be subjective, I just wanted to know what the differences were.

Comment: Ars Technica has also done a write-up: http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/news/2011/02/hands-on-android-market-website-improved-still-lags-appbrain.ars

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Features appbrain has that the Market site doesn't:

- Ability to save lists and keep them private or share them
- Appbrain reviews on top of market reviews
- More sharing options
- More filtering options for browsing
- Lists of popular apps
- App recommendations based on what you have installed
- Shows the total amount you've spent on paid apps

Features the market site has that appbrain doesn't:

- Two added categories: Widgets & Live Wallpapers
- Ability to install to device from websites without having to have an addon app that you have to periodically reauthorize like appbrain
- Easily choose which device to install to if you have multiple devices
- Ability to buy apps from the site
- Shows videos that the developers have added to their market page

These are all obviously subject to change.

Answer (score 3):

Mathijs Vogelzang, developer of AppBrain.com, answers (well tries to) this question in [this article](http://www.quora.com/Mathijs-Vogelzang-How-will-AppBrain-respond-to-the-launch-of-an-official-web-interface-for-the-Android-Market).

Answer (score 0):

In the handset applications, AppBrain does everything that the Android Market app does, and adds filtering options such as price, popularity, etc. that the Android Market app does not (at this time). AppBrain also offers the ability to follow others and share app lists.